# Is there a way to obtain in Spring the list of path variables from the URI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httprequest, path-variables

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{ids}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMethod(@PathVariable List<String> ids){

}
```

I would like something similar, but I need the request to map to something like: `localhost:8080/id1/id2/id3/.../idn`

I don’t know the number of path variables (ids) and neither their names.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a path it essentially adds to the uri . The uri has length limitations.
Related post : [Maximum length of HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

So it is not advisable to add multiple number of parameters to the uri as path variable, when the number is not restricted.

You could use query params like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{ids}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMethod(@RequestParam("myparam") List<String> ids) 
{ 
}
```

Instead what you could have is convert it to a post request and have a request body with the list of data as an object.

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity postController(
  @RequestBody CustomPojo data) {
 
    exampleService.fakeAuthenticate(data);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}

class CustomPoJo {
  List<String> ids;
//getter setter etc
}
```

and the json could look like :

```
{"custompojo":["id1","id2"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done since the request will look for endpoint having matching URL and matching method.